# Spark Performance Question - Tracking Memory Usage

Tags: apache-spark, memory

I'm currently working on performance & memory tuning for a spark process. As part of this I'm performing multiple runs of different versions of the code and trying to compare their results side by side.

I've got a few questions to ask, so I'll post each separately so they can be addressed separately.

One of the areas I'm trying to improve on is memory usage - the existing process is struggling when processing larger volumes of data. But while I've been able to identify some areas for improvement I've been unable to find a way to measure the benefit in terms of memory usage (and since this is a performance tuning task, measuring the actual benefit is essential).

What's a good way to get more insight into the memory usage of a Spark task? Ideally I'd like to know average & peak usage for each task run, and be able to identify which tasks contribute most to that.

Comment: Have you tried the spark ui, you can see memory used for each task/job and see if some task need more memory than others.

Comment: Working on that at the moment - biggest annoyance is that if I run multiple jobs using the same script as a testing batch they all become the same job. But I may be able to address that by running them independently.

Comment: Also it would be nice to be able to dig into the detail a bit more so I can figure out where the memory is being used.